# Integration of $\frac{1}{1-\cos(\alpha)\cos x }$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, contest-math

Integration of $\dfrac{1}{1-\cos(\alpha)\cos x }$ w.r.t $x$

How to do this problem? I was trying to reduce it $\dfrac{1}{1-\cos(\alpha)\cos (x) }=\dfrac{\sec (\alpha)}{\sec (\alpha)-\cos (x) }$. But I can't put it in shape.

**After seeing comments:**

$\dfrac{1}{1-\cos(\alpha)\cos (x) }=\dfrac{1}{1-\cos (\alpha)\frac{1-\tan^2 (x/2)}{1+tan^2(x/2)}}=\dfrac{\sec^2(x/2)}{1+\tan^2(x/2)-\cos(\alpha)+\cos(\alpha)\tan^2(x/2) }$. Now taking $\tan(x/2)=z$ we are done.

Comment: Do you mean integration with respect to $x$?

Comment: Use tangent half angle formulas (see paragraph "use in integral calculus" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Substitute $$u=\tan\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)$$ then you will have $$du=\frac{1}{2}\sec^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)dx$$
For your work: A possible result should  be $$2 \csc (\alpha ) \tan ^{-1}\left(\sin
   \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\alpha }{2}\right) \csc
   \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}+\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)+C$$

Comment: See my edit if it seems to be correct to you.